# Как избавиться от совета браузера

Tags: firefox, ajax, javascript, aspx

Есть textbox на aspx странице, в нем событие, по которому отправляется запрос на сервер. Результат выводится рядом с textbox в виде обычного совета. Проблема: браузер вместе с моим советом выводит свой совет со списком ранее введённых в это поле значений. Как программно избавится от совета браузера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно сделать так:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

"Хинт , -а, м.
(айтишники)
значение: совет,
рекомендация,
инструкция."
дабы не вызывать взрыв мозгов и яростное гугление пишите, пожалуйста, на русском языке.

чтобы не кешировался текстбокс в абсолютно всех браузерах можно использовать хитрость:
в форму добавлять <input name="rnd" value="1234321" type="hidden/">
<input name="string1234321"/>
в скрипте при получении ответа проверяете не $_POST['string'] a $_POST['string'+$_POST['rnd']] в случае если сервер на PHP.